# How to set global variable with Power Apps OnStart property

Tags: variables, canvas, global-variables, powerapps, onstart

I have created blank canvas app and I want to create product details like product name, price, category,quantity, color, etc..., by using set function with OnStart property. Please, suggest any information about this.

I want to create global variable with Onstart property in blank canvas app.

Comment: Suggest any solution...

Comment: Hi @GaneshM, Did you try my solution given below? Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you in any way & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily. It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 2):

If you have fixed set of products, you can write function like below in `OnStart` property of `App` object in your app:

```
Set (
    gvProducts,
    Table(
        {
            ProductName: "Product 1", 
            Price: 100,
            Category: "Category 1",
            Quantity: 5,
            Color: "Red"
        },
        {
            ProductName: "Product 2", 
            Price: 200,
            Category: "Category 2",
            Quantity: 10,
            Color: "Green"
        }
    )
)
```

It creates table of multiple records with same properties. You can adjust the data type of each property and add multiple records/objects as per your requirements.

[image]

Comment: alternatively you can use the same logic in the OnVisible property of the screen you set in the App.StartScreen property.  Here's some detailed opinion why this is preferable: https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/app-startscreen-a-new-declarative-alternative-to-navigate-in-app-onstart/

Comment: You can also use collections instead of global variable for storing multiple records/array.